# Update Child ForeignKey using Nhibernate Stateless Session

Tags: nhibernate, orm, stateless-session

I understand that while using the stateless session one must explicitly save an object association (child)

If I have the following objects:

```
public class Parent()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public IList<Child> Childs {get;set;}
}

public class Child()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I modify an instance of parent and add one child to it, I then save the parent and child using the following statements:

```
statelesssession.Update(parentInstance);
statelesssession.Insert(parentInstance.Childs.Last());
```

Doing this updates sucessfully the parent and creates the child record, however the field Parent_Id from the Child Table stays null, therefore there the association is not recorded.

How can I manually record the association using the stateless session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a `many-to-one` property on `Child` that points back to `Parent`.  That's what NHibernate would use for saving the `Parent_id` column.  You need:

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Parent Parent {get;set;} // this is missing
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

... and the corresponding NHibernate mapping.  Also, make sure that you set the value of `child.Parent` when you add the child to the parent.

Another thing, given the sequence of events you describe ("I create an instance of parent and add one child to it") I would have expected to see an `Insert` for the parent instead of an `Update`.

Comment: Yes but I want the relationship to be one-way, parent to child only.  I meant how to accomplish this with a one way relationship.

Comment: If you don't have a reference to the parent class you at least need a field mapped to the parent id in the child.  It's just like any other column at that point.